# How to properly compute weighted average for zeroes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following problem - I'm computing weighted average in SQL, as following: `SUM(Value * Weight) / SUM(Weight)`. However, there can be issue that rows are empty => `SUM(Weight) == 0)`, and in this case the query fails. Is it somehow possible to return '0' as result in this case?

I have tried `CASE SUM(Weight) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(Value * Weight) / SUM(Weight) END`, but I'm afraid that it evaluates `SUM(Weight)` twice, and that can be fairly expensive in my case.

Comment: SQL Server might be just smart enough to not force that evaluation twice. Did you try it and compare the differences (e.g. on a table with no NULLs/0s)?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the overhead of calculating `SUM(Weight)` twice, unless you are using a UDF for the `sum()`.  The overhead of identifying the groups and bringing the data together would typically be much, much more than the overhead of adding up some numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NULLIF` and `ISNULL`:

```
ISNULL(SUM(Value * Weight) / NULLIF(SUM(Weight),0),0)
```

Comment: I'd say that that won't help. I don't have NULLs there.

Comment: @Yossarian What do you mean?, did you try that code?. I'm converting `SUM(Weight)` to `NULL` if the value is `0` so the division evaluates to `NULL` and then using `ISNULL` to convert the total result to `0`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I only misread it - that code makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL engine doesn't compute `sum(Weight)` twice, just once. The conceptual process is:

- compute the full cartesian join of all tables in the from clause
- apply the join criteria to filter the results
- apply the `where` clause criteria to filter the results
- partition this result set into groups as defined by the `group by` clause
- collapse each such group into one row, computing any aggregate functions that have been specified, keeping only those columns listed in the result set (aggregrate functions and grouping columns),
- apply the criteria in the `having` clause to filter the grouped results,
- drop all columns but those specified in the queries result columns, creating those that are computed expressions.
- apply the ordering specified in the `order by` statement.

No actual SQL engine does this, but it must behave as if that is what happened. Your aggregate function is computed just once, along with any other aggregate functions, in a single pass.

Comment: I have no idea how that bulleted list supports the idea that in a real databases, `sum(Weight)` would not be computed twice in the OP's question.